# What is the probability of winning this game?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> A tennis player has a 60% chance of winning any given point in a tennis game. Calculate the probability that she will win the game within the first 6 points, stating any assumptions you make.
>
> (A game is won when a player has won at least 4 points and won at least 2 more points than their opponent.)

So there are 3 choices:

1. she wins 4 points with the probability 60%$^{4}$
2. she wins 4 points and lose 1 point with probability 4 $\times$ 60%$^{4}$ $\times$ 40%
3. she wins 4 points and lose 2 points 15 $\times$ 60%$^{4}$ $\times$ 40%$^{2}$

So the total probability of her winning the game is 0.69984. Is this right?

Comment: You counted some scenarios multiple times. The scenario where she wins all 4 points are considered in all three choices that you stated

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the justification for $15$ in your third point?

Comment: @user3733558 it was the number of different ways scenario 3 could have happened. so 6C2 OR 6C4

Comment: @Elise which is why I wanted to draw your attention to it: winning the game means that the winner won the last point. So you don't have 6C2 possibilities, only 5C2.

Answer (score 1):

To win in $\leq 6$ points, she must lose at most $2$ points in $6$, so

P(win) = $\binom 6 0\cdot 0.4^0\cdot 0.6^6 + \binom 6 1\cdot 0.4^1\cdot 0.6^5  + \binom 6 2\cdot  0.4^2 \cdot 0.6^4 = 0.54432$

---

**PS**

The above formulation is the simplest way to get the answer. However, just for corroboration, let us also solve it by summing up

P(win in **exactly** $4,5,\;or\; 6$) points

To win in *exactly* $4$ points, she must win all: $0.6^4 =0.1296$

To win in $5$ points, she must win the fifth point and three of the first four: $\left(\binom 4 3 \cdot 0.6^3\cdot0.4\right)\cdot0.6 = 0.20736$

To win in $6$ points, she must win the sixth point, and three of the first five:$\left(\binom 5 3 \cdot 0.6^3\cdot0.4^2\right)\cdot0.6 = 0.20736$

$0.1296+ 0.20736 +0.20736 = 0.54432$, as before

But error prone method with possibly confusing binomial coefficients

Answer (score 0):

Using Stars and Bars, the correct answer is:

$$P(\text{win})=\binom{3}{0}0.6^4+\binom{4}{1}0.6^4\times0.4+\binom{5}{2}0.6^4\times0.4^2$$
$$=0.54432$$

She must win the last point, and so the sums represent 3 wins no losses, 3 wins 1 loss and 3 wins 2 losses in the preceding points of the game.

Comment: and the reason for the DV is ...

Comment: **1** Sorry, but the answer is incorrect. Applying a sanity check, with probability of a single win being $0.6$, that of a game win can't $>0.6$. **2** The method used is not stars and bars.

Comment: 1. OP has answer >0.6 as well. 2. It is S&B: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29, with points for and points against. @trueblueanil;

Comment: WADR, stars and bars is the technique applied to place identical objects into distinct bins. Also, OP is asking whether his answer is right.

Comment: @trueblueanil; with the four bins: xPxPxPxP, where x is a slot and P is a point won by our heroine, and losing points being the identical objects.

Comment: :Surely we are talking of a binomial distribution, maybe with particular conditions.

Comment: @trueblueanil; yeah, I just got the sums wrong - it was early!